# Coin tossing and counting heads

Tags: probability

Toss coins with probability $p_i$ of getting a head. Call the number of coin tosses you need on average until you get the first head $A$. The number of tosses you need to get an average of at least one head is the smallest integer $y$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^{y} p_i \geq  1$.

> When is it true that $y \geq A$?  Is it true if the $p_i$ are non-decreasing?

Comment: I think you need to work on these definitions some more. "Probability of getting a head until you get a head"... what does that mean?

Comment: @julien Corrected. Thank you.

Comment: See the [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: Not sure if I get this still.  Let $p_i = \frac{2}{3}, \forall i > 0$.  What is $y$?

Comment: @Macavity Solve $2y/3 =1$ so $y=3/2$.  Round up to $2$.

Comment: @julien. The $p_i$ can all be different. (Also made crucial edit to the second sentence.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the number of the coin toss when the first head appears. For every nonnegative integer $n$, let $Q(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}p_i\mathbf 1_{i\leqslant n}$. Thus, $A$ and $y$ are uniquely defined by the identity $A=E[T]$ and by the fact that $Q(y)\geqslant1\gt Q(y-1)$.

Extend $Q$ to the nonnegative real line by linear interpolation and assume that the extended function $Q$ is convex. This is equivalent to the fact that $(p_i)_{i\geqslant1}$ is nondecreasing.

Then, Jensen inequality yields $Q(A)\leqslant E[Q(T)]$. For every $i\geqslant1$, $P[T\geqslant i]=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{i-1}(1-p_n)$. Hence, $E[Q(T)]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}p_iP[T\geqslant i]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}p_i\prod\limits_{n=1}^{i-1}(1-p_n)=1-\prod\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1-p_n)\leqslant1.$ In particular $Q(A)\leqslant1$, which implies that $A\leqslant y$.

> If the sequence $(p_i)_{i\geqslant1}$ is nondecreasing, then $y\geqslant A$.

As an example in the other direction, assume that $p_i\lt1$ for every $i\geqslant1$ and that $\sum\limits_ip_i$ converges. Then the event "no head ever" has positive probability hence $A$ is infinite and the inequality $y\geqslant A$ cannot hold in full generality.

Comment: Why is $E[Q(T)]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}p_iP[T\geqslant i]$ true?

Comment: Because $Q(T)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}p_i\mathbf 1_{T\geqslant i}$, by definition of $Q$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a reference for this problem?

Comment: None that I would be aware of.

Comment: Dunno. What did you try?